# I Installed Pip But It Won't Execute Any Commands

Tags: python, cmd, jupyter-notebook

```
C:\Users\Danie>py -3.11 -m pip install pip
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\danie\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (22.3.1)

C:\Users\Danie>pip install notebook
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I don't understand why it still won't work? Does anyone know why?

Comment: What does `py -3.11 -m pip install notebook` give you? It seems your python 3.11 installation is not on your `%PATH%`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a "Scripts" path that needs to be added to the "path" in the environment variables.

Environment Variables > PATH EDIT > NEW PATH >

```
C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\
```

If this path doesn't exist, you should add this as well.

```
"C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\"
```

If the problems do not go away, I suggest you do a clean python installation, add "path" to your environment variables in the python installation screen?